# DataSet on Webserver

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services, dataset

Im trying to implement something given to me however I've come across an error

when using:

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataSet getAll()
    {
```

DataSet isnt recognised. Im guessing I'm missing one of the "using System..." statement from the start but I dont know what it is. I was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Im using Visual Studio 2008

Comment: As mentioned below System.DataSet is what you need, you can also put your cursor anywhere on the DataSet and do "Ctrl-Period(Full stop for Europeans hehe)" and it will pop up intellisense of what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Data` is what you need.